# How to parse a more complicated JSON object in Ruby on Sinatra

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I'm a Java guy, new to Ruby. I've been playing with it just to see what it can do, and I'm running into an issue that I can't solve.

I decided to try out Sinatra, again, just to see what it can do, and decided to play with the ESPN API and see if I can pull the venue of a team via the API.

I'm able to make the call and get the data back, but I am having trouble parsing it:

```
{"sports"=>[{"name"=>"baseball", "id"=>1, "uid"=>"s:1", "leagues"=>[{"name"=>"Major League Baseball", "abbreviation"=>"mlb", "id"=>10, "uid"=>"s:1~l:10", "groupId"=>9, "shortName"=>"MLB", "teams"=>[{"id"=>17, "uid"=>"s:1~l:10~t:17", "location"=>"Cincinnati", "name"=>"Reds", "abbreviation"=>"CIN", "color"=>"D60042", "venues"=>[{"id"=>83, "name"=>"Great American Ball Park", "city"=>"Cincinnati", "state"=>"Ohio", "country"=>"", "capacity"=>0}], "links"=>{"api"=>{"teams"=>{"href"=>"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17"}, "news"=>{"href"=>"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news"}, "notes"=>{"href"=>"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news/notes"}}, "web"=>{"teams"=>{"href"=>"http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/cin/cincinnati-reds?ex_cid=espnapi_public"}}, "mobile"=>{"teams"=>{"href"=>"http://m.espn.go.com/mlb/clubhouse?teamId=17&ex_cid=espnapi_public"}}}}]}]}], "resultsOffset"=>0, "resultsLimit"=>50, "resultsCount"=>1, "timestamp"=>"2013-08-04T14:47:13Z", "status"=>"success"}
```

I want to pull the venues part of the object, specifically the name value. Every time I try to parse it I end up getting an error along the lines of "cannot change from nil to string" and then also I've gotten an integer to string error.

Here's what i have so far:

```
get '/venue/:team' do

    id = ids[params[:team]]
    url = 'http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/' + id + '?enable=venues&apikey=' + $key
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    data = resp.body
    parsed = JSON.parse(resp.body)
    #venueData = parsed["sports"]

    "Looking for the venue of the #{params[:team]}, which has id " + id + ", and here's the data returned: " + venueData.to_s

end
```

When I do parsed["sports"} I get:

```
 [{"name"=>"baseball", "id"=>1, "uid"=>"s:1", "leagues"=>[{"name"=>"Major League Baseball", "abbreviation"=>"mlb", "id"=>10, "uid"=>"s:1~l:10", "groupId"=>9, "shortName"=>"MLB", "teams"=>[{"id"=>17, "uid"=>"s:1~l:10~t:17", "location"=>"Cincinnati", "name"=>"Reds", "abbreviation"=>"CIN", "color"=>"D60042", "venues"=>[{"id"=>83, "name"=>"Great American Ball Park", "city"=>"Cincinnati", "state"=>"Ohio", "country"=>"", "capacity"=>0}], "links"=>{"api"=>{"teams"=>{"href"=>"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17"}, "news"=>{"href"=>"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news"}, "notes"=>{"href"=>"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news/notes"}}, "web"=>{"teams"=>{"href"=>"http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/cin/cincinnati-reds?ex_cid=espnapi_public"}}, "mobile"=>{"teams"=>{"href"=>"http://m.espn.go.com/mlb/clubhouse?teamId=17&ex_cid=espnapi_public"}}}}]}]}]
```

But nothing else parses. Please help!

Like I said, I'm not trying to do anything fancy, just figure out Ruby a little for fun, but I have been stuck on this issue for days now. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

JSON straight from the API:

```
{"sports" :[{"name" :"baseball","id" :1,"uid" :"s:1","leagues" :[{"name" :"Major League Baseball","abbreviation" :"mlb","id" :10,"uid" :"s:1~l:10","groupId" :9,"shortName" :"MLB","teams" :[{"id" :17,"uid" :"s:1~l:10~t:17","location" :"Cincinnati","name" :"Reds","abbreviation" :"CIN","color" :"D60042","venues" :[{"id" :83,"name" :"Great American Ball Park","city" :"Cincinnati","state" :"Ohio","country" :"","capacity" :0}],"links" :{"api" :{"teams" :{"href" :"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17"},"news" :{"href" :"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news"},"notes" :{"href" :"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news/notes"}},"web" :{"teams" :{"href" :"http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/cin/cincinnati-reds?ex_cid=espnapi_public"}},"mobile" :{"teams" :{"href" :"http://m.espn.go.com/mlb/clubhouse?teamId=17&ex_cid=espnapi_public"}}}}]}]}],"resultsOffset" :0,"resultsLimit" :50,"resultsCount" :1,"timestamp" :"2013-08-05T19:44:32Z","status" :"success"}
```

The result of data.inspect:

```
"{\"sports\" :[{\"name\" :\"baseball\",\"id\" :1,\"uid\" :\"s:1\",\"leagues\" :[{\"name\" :\"Major League Baseball\",\"abbreviation\" :\"mlb\",\"id\" :10,\"uid\" :\"s:1~l:10\",\"groupId\" :9,\"shortName\" :\"MLB\",\"teams\" :[{\"id\" :17,\"uid\" :\"s:1~l:10~t:17\",\"location\" :\"Cincinnati\",\"name\" :\"Reds\",\"abbreviation\" :\"CIN\",\"color\" :\"D60042\",\"venues\" :[{\"id\" :83,\"name\" :\"Great American Ball Park\",\"city\" :\"Cincinnati\",\"state\" :\"Ohio\",\"country\" :\"\",\"capacity\" :0}],\"links\" :{\"api\" :{\"teams\" :{\"href\" :\"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17\"},\"news\" :{\"href\" :\"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news\"},\"notes\" :{\"href\" :\"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/teams/17/news/notes\"}},\"web\" :{\"teams\" :{\"href\" :\"http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/cin/cincinnati-reds?ex_cid=espnapi_public\"}},\"mobile\" :{\"teams\" :{\"href\" :\"http://m.espn.go.com/mlb/clubhouse?teamId=17&ex_cid=espnapi_public\"}}}}]}]}],\"resultsOffset\" :0,\"resultsLimit\" :50,\"resultsCount\" :1,\"timestamp\" :\"2013-08-05T19:44:24Z\",\"status\" :\"success\"}"
```

Comment: That isn't JSON you've provided, but an array of hashes, which I'm guessing you got _after_ parsing, so it's not going to be a parsing problem! ;) @kAlmAcetA gives a good answer.

Comment: So how would I pull the venues data in Ruby? When I try parsed["venues"], I get nil. I haven't done much in Ruby so this is all very foreign to me.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there :) If you can, post up the output of `warn data.inspect` and then we can see the JSON the ESPN API responds with (minus any sensitive data) as it appears it's not in there to begin with, but it would be good to check.

Comment: Question updated with the requested info. Thanks again, I'm quite excited to learn more about using Ruby like this.

Comment: So, here's the result of parsed.inspect: 
"venues"=>[{"id"=>83, "name"=>"Great American Ball Park", "city"=>"Cincinnati", "state"=>"Ohio", "country"=>"", "capacity"=>0}]

"venues" has data, so why is it coming up nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `data` you've provided in the question, you can get to the `venues` information like this:

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.parse data

json["sports"].first["leagues"].first["teams"].first["venues"]
# => [{"id"=>83, "name"=>"Great American Ball Park", "city"=>"Cincinnati", "state"=>"Ohio", "country"=>"", "capacity"=>0}]
```

By replacing each of the `first` calls with an iterator, you can search through without knowing where the data is:

```
json["sports"].each{|h|
  h["leagues"].each{|h|
    h["teams"].each{|h|
      venues = h["venues"].map{|h| h["name"]}.join(", ")
      puts %Q!name: #{h["location"]} #{h["name"]} venues: #{venues}!
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs:

> name: Cincinnati Reds venues: Great American Ball Park

Depending on how stable the response data is you may be able to cut out several of the iterators:

```
json["sports"].first["leagues"]
              .first["teams"]
              .each{|h|
                venues = h["venues"].map{|h| h["name"] }.join(", ")
                puts %Q!name: #{h["location"]} #{h["name"]} venues: #{venues}!
              }
```

and you'll most likely want to save the data, so something like [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is helpful:

```
team_and_venues = json["sports"].first["leagues"]
              .first["teams"]
              .each_with_object([]){|h,xs|
                venues = h["venues"].map{|h| h["name"]}.join(", ")
                xs << %Q!name: #{h["location"]} #{h["name"]} venues: #{venues}!
              }
# => ["name: Cincinnati Reds venues: Great American Ball Park"]

team_and_venues
# => ["name: Cincinnati Reds venues: Great American Ball Park"]
```

Notice that when an iterator declares variables, even if there is a variable with the same name outside the block, the scope of the block is respected and the block's variables remain local.

That's some pretty ugly code if you ask me, but it's a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

`parsed["sports"]` does not exist, parse your input and inspect it/ dump it

Comment: Oh, that's the JSON response for parsed["sports'], it's the only thing I could parse from the original. I've edited the original question with the full JSON response